# Can I edit dictionaries created by dictreader in python

Tags: python

I am trying to edit values in dictionaries created by dictreader. If I understand this correctly, it creates a list of dictionaries. This part is working fine. However, I'd like to change some of the values for the key:value pairs in certain dictionaries and this is not functioning the way I expect. After I finish editing the values, my dictreader object seems to be completely empty.

To deal with this, I make an empty list (elis) and then fill it with all the dictionaries that were in the dictreader object.

My code follows:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Load the csv into a dictreader object
elistable = csv.DictReader(open(&quot;./elispotable.csv&quot;, &#39;rU&#39;))

# This code will print all the dictionaries when uncommented
# for item in elis:
#   print item

# Create an empty list 
elis=[]

#Note that the dicts have keys including &#39;Control&#39; and &#39;Peptide Id&#39; 

for item in elistable:
    if item[&#39;Control&#39;]==&#39;Neg&#39;:
        item[&#39;Peptide Id&#39;]=&#39;Neg&#39;
    if item[&#39;Control&#39;]==&#39;Pos&#39;:
        item[&#39;Peptide Id&#39;]=&#39;Pos&#39;
    elis.append(item)

#Elis is now full with all the dictionaries and correct values that were edited in the for loop

dude=[]
for item in elistable:
    dude.append(item)

print dude
```

Dude is totally empty and if I try to run a for loop to print the dicts from elistable, nothing prints. It works before I run the for loop with if statements, but not after. It seems to be completely empty now.

Is it possible to edit the values in the dictionaries created by the dictreader? Am I somehow overwriting them all?

Comment: Just a tip: you don't have to use HTML to write posts. [Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) is much easier to use and will render code blocks with syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thank you. This is embarrassing, but I actually managed to mess up copying this from Macdown (a markdown editor). It looks like I butchered quite a few of my special characters. I'll be more careful in the future.

Comment: No worries everyone has to learn sometime :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I understand this correctly, it creates a list of dictionaries.

It doesn't; a DictReader is an iterator that generates the next dictionary when you request it. As with all Python iterators (and as with regular file object iteration), if you try to iterate over it twice, the second loop will see the iterator as empty, since the iterator doesn't go back to the start after the first loop.

If you want a list, call `list` on it:

```
elistable = list(csv.DictReader(open("./elispotable.csv", 'rU')))
```

Separate loops will then use separate iterators over the list.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense, and looks like a more efficient way of loading this iterator into a list compared to my for loop.